# How to make the compiler aware of templated struct?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement an [answer given on my question over at CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142278/56066). Basically, I want to access some static variables in a templated struct. Consider the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<const int idx>
struct Data{
    static int bar;
};

template<const int idx>
int getBar(){
    return Data<idx>::bar;
}

int main() {
    const int n = 2; // Arbitrary number
    cout << getBar<n>();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler does not recognize that I want `Data<n>` to be available in the program - however, it recognizes the initial `getBar<n>` function just fine as is evident from the error message:

```
undefined reference to `Data<2>::bar'
```

How do I tell the compiler to make the templated struct available as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static class variables must be given memory allocation. Add this:

```
template<const int idx>
int Data<idx>::bar = 0;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90ca74b74e25f3b3)

Edit: The dupe linked by NathanOliver hits it on the head, but for non-templated classes. This answer shows the syntax when the class is templated. minor difference, but still useful.

Comment: Thanks - I wouldn't not have gotten this from the question marked as dupe.